# Is gun control effective?

Tags: law, weapons, criminology

I have seen numerous arguments about gun control, in the sense of laws restricting gun ownership or possession, and whether widespread gun possession affects crime rates, and each side is happy to pull out studies that are favorable to their side.  I really haven't felt I could trust any of them.

I hope this isn't too much of a hot potato, but are there any serious scientific studies available?  Or at least reasonably unbiased?

Comment: Gun control is a large umbrella that encompasses a large number of policies. Do you really really any type of gun control or are you referring to a particular policy (prohibition, registry, etc.)?

Comment: @Borror0:  I'll take anything I can get.  The arguments are wide-ranging, and I haven't found anything I trust yet on any of them.

Comment: When looking at gun control you also need to look closely at gun culture. They are closely related because from what I have seen tight gun control does not necessarily correlate to gun related injury or deaths.

Comment: This question is not very good. What about the effects of *removing* gun control? Without both sides of the equation it's impossible to remove any cultural effects for example.

Comment: @Sklivvz: It's possible the question could be refined, but I think it's an important one to ask. (I have a strong personal bias, but unbiased information on the subject seems hard to find.)

Comment: @Sklivvz:  I didn't think I was addressing the effects of passing gun control laws and not the effects of repealing them.  Obviously, both would be useful to study.  If you have suggestions on how to improve the question, please make them.

Comment: I believe your question is asking if governmental gun control laws are effective.  The government itself, however, is the largest perpetrator of [violence][1].  If gun control laws are needed then the the government itself should be the first target for such restrictions.


  [1]: http://edfriendly.blogspot.com/2011/02/death-by-government-why-you-are-46.html

Comment: In regards to Mark's study that claims that gun control laws were the reasons for reduced homicide rates starting in the 90s. Freakonomics covered this topic and statistically showed that it was in fact the legalization of abortion that resulted in not only the lower homicide rates but also the reduced crime rates. Most aborted fetuses came from what would have been lower income families, which tend to commit higher rates of crime. It is no coincidence that the reductions began 18 years after abortion became legal.

Comment: @Dunk, yikes! That sounds like Minority Report taken to the extreme. Or worse. At least the Nazis allowed their sub-standard citizens to be born before eugenising them...

Comment: @Benjol:  We're not talking about government-imposed abortions.  The usual reason a woman would have an abortion is that she doesn't feel ready to raise a child, for some reason, and has become pregnant.  This means that abortion reduces the number of badly raised children, and apparently therefore the crime rate later on.  This has nothing to do with any sort of agenda or social control.  (I refuse to get involved in a pro- or anti-abortion argument here.)

Comment: A couple of links worth considering: http://shanghaiist.com/2012/12/15/the_lower_death_toll_in_chinese_sch.php  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/School_attacks_in_China_(2010%E2%80%932011)

Comment: [meta here](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2040/evidence-for-gun-control-question-needs-rethink)

Comment: I don't believe that laws can significantly affect culture. For example Canada has way more relaxed gun laws than Connecticut, yet much less gun homicides. OTOH, Mexico has formally very strict gun laws, which totally doesn't matter in places like Juarez.

Comment: There are two questions here often confused. One is whether gun control works in general (international comparisons suggest they do). The other is whether introducing them in north America would work. The second isn't the same as the first as, unless all states in the USA plus Mexico and Canada introduced the laws, they wouldn't work well because of "leakage" across borders. This is also why comparing gun laws in different US states doesn't generate useful stats on the topic.

Comment: @matt I agree. I think the key point are the implementation details. Removing a large proportion of gun from streets and homes is guaranteed to work, however not all gun control policies are effective in actually reducing the number of guns significantly. The devil is in the details.

Comment: @matt_black: I don't see how international comparisons are conclusive. USA is clearly outlier here. But you have countries like Canada, Austria with liberal gun laws, low gun crimes; Israel and Switzerland where most adults have military assault rifles at home (although civilian use is forbidden); OTOH, you have Mexico, which has very strict gun laws, Russia with rather strict ones too; and high murder rates in both of them. Also UK is often given as example of success of gun control, however homicides didn't drop significantly, they are just committed with knifes, not guns.

Comment: " One is whether gun control works in general (international comparisons suggest they do)" and works at achieving WHAT? Gun control is very effective at turning citizens into victims of crime. They're potentially effective at reducing gun violence, but at the cost of increasing other means of killing each other (knives, clubs, poison, arson).

Comment: Harvard School of Public Health summarises the available studies on a wide range of different aspects of gun control, here: http://www.hsph.harvard.edu/hicrc/firearms-research/

Comment: @vartec: Concerning Israel and Switzerland: "Compared with the United States, Switzerland and Israel have lower rates of gun ownership, stricter gun control laws, and their policies discourage gun ownership.
Rosenbaum, Janet E. Gun utopias? Firearm access and ownership in Israel and Switzerland. Journal of Public Health Policy. 2012; 33:46-58." http://www.hsph.harvard.edu/hicrc/firearms-research/other-countries/

Comment: @jwenting re self-defence: "Most purported self-defense gun uses are gun uses in escalating arguments and are both socially undesirable and illegal. Hemenway, David; Miller, Matthew; Azrael, Deborah. Gun use in the United States: Results from two national surveys. Injury Prevention. 2000; 6:263-267." http://www.hsph.harvard.edu/hicrc/firearms-research/gun-threats-and-self-defense-gun-use-2/

Comment: This is a huge topic [for freakonomics](http://freakonomics.com/2013/02/14/how-to-think-about-guns-a-new-freakonomics-radio-podcast/). They usually come up with awesome clever ways of resolving issues from an economist point of view and yet I think they also don't know an answer to this! :O

Answer (score 49):

I don’t know how well a single case-study can be generalised, or applied in a different cultural setting. But since [jozzas’ answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/976/is-gun-control-effective/3535#3535) on the Australian gun control act exclusively relies on a paper that completely misrepresents the evidence here’s another stab at it:

### Background

In 1996, after a [mass shooting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_Arthur_massacre_(Australia)) with an illegally purchased but legally available [semi-automatic weapon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-automatic_firearm) in Port Arthur, Tasmania that killed 35 people and wounded 23, Australia enacted the *National Firearms Agreement* (NFA), a strict ban on semi-automatic weapons and stricter requirements for acquiring a weapon permit. They also enacted a compulsory gun buyback scheme taking effect immediately which resulted in [600,000 guns being bought back from the state, at a cost of 500 million AUS$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_buy-back_scheme#In_Australia). The government levied a 1% addition in income tax for one year to finance this.

### Data & evidence

The following gives a broad overview over a huge mass of data. I tried my hardest to represent the data fairly; however, by necessity I leave out quite a lot (otherwise I’d have to publish a paper). Most of the missing data and justifications can be found in Leigh & Neill [2] which gives a truly excellent run-down of the evidence, along with a careful explanation and justification of the statistical methods used, and a *comprehensive explanation of the limitations of the data*. In fact, this latter point makes the paper stand out particularly.

- **Massacres.** In the 18 years prior to the enactment of the NFA, [there had been 13 massacres in Australia involving guns](http://www.smh.com.au/opinion/society-and-culture/slow-erosion-of-gun-laws-presages-another-tragedy-20110427-1dwmx.html) (defined as killing ≥ 4 people). In the years since, [there have been none](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/12/16/opinion/sunday/kristof-do-we-have-the-courage-to-stop-this.html). However, while such large-scale killings are obviously tragic events they contribute relatively little to the overall rates of deaths by guns.
- **Murder rate.** Australia has generally had [low levels of violent crime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_politics_in_Australia#The_Port_Arthur_massacre_and_its_consequences) even before the ban. Furthermore, there’s been a steady decline in the number of firearm-related deaths since the early 1980s [1, 2], in particular, there was a 47% decrease between 1991 and 2000. This was accompanied by a similar decrease in non-firearm related murders.

  On the other hand, there was a clear acceleration of the reduction after the NFA was enacted, but [2] found that this reduction falls short of statistical significance.
- **Suicide rate.** What they managed to show, though, was that the NFA buyback contributed strongly and significantly to a reduction in suicides. To ensure that they weren’t just looking at a reduction over time which started before the NFA, they compared *across states* and correlated reduction with number of guns bought back by the state, and find that more gun buyback by the state results in more reduction in suicide with a statistically significant trend (*R*<sup>2</sup> = 0.7685, *p*-value = 0.004% – this is a *very* robust statistic that cannot be explained away by any other factors that the authors examined). The gun buyback led to a reduction by 1.9 per 100,000 for each 3.500 withdrawn guns per 100.000 individuals (95% CI), which is a 74% reduction.

  This state-dependent trend and its correlation is shown here:

  [image: change in firearm suicide versus gun buyback]
- **Compensation.** Both murder and suicide rates declined *globally*, that is, reductions in gun death weren’t increased by use of other weapons. However, in the first few years after the NFA, non-gun suicides were briefly raised, continuing a prior trend, before dropping as well. No such trend exists for homicides.
- **Cost.** The gun buyback cost 500 million AUS$. On the other hand, [2] estimates that the 200 annual deaths thus prevented correspond to an economic saving of 500 million AUS$ *per year*. This would correspond to a 7 *billion* AUS$ cost saving.

  Could this money have spent differently to get a similar (or better) reduction in gun-related deaths? I couldn’t find any data analysing this. However, the buyback was essentially a *one-off* cost so amortised over time no *ongoing* intervention could have a better cost-benefit relation.

### Significance

As mentioned, the robust data analysis shows a marked reduction in suicide rates. [2] goes into more detail to improve the robustness of the analysis by doing subsampling and trying (unsuccessfully) to explain the reduction with other variables.

Lee & Suardi [3] have argued that no such reduction exists for homicide rates because the time series data doesn’t show a “structural break”. That may be so ([2] didn’t find a statistically significant reduction for homicide rates either). However, [2] notes that such structural breaks cannot be assumed to exist due to the large number of factors influencing death rates.

Baker & McPhedran [4] claim that even the suicide rate reduction is not related to the NFA buyback. However, [2] notes that this paper is deeply flawed since it wouldn’t infer significance even if homicide rates had been *negative* in the years after 2004, and that the authors of [4] “should know better”.

**Overall**, the NFA and buyback were correlated with a significant reduction in firearms related deaths, and no balancing increase in non-firearms related deaths.

### Putting things into perspective

Is this evidence convincing? Yes: It is the best evidence we have, and while statistically flawed methods find no effect, correcting statistical mistakes invariably finds a significant reduction. And in fact, it is the *best evidence we could hope for*, because it is the kind of signal we would *expect* to get if we *knew* that there were a real effect: no sharp break but a steady decline. In fact, in the words of the authors of [2],

> from the perspective of 1996, **it would have been difficult to imagine more compelling future evidence of a beneficial effect of the law.**

---

### Notable references

- [1] Jenny Mouzos & Catherine Rushforth, [“Firearm related deaths in Australia, 1991–2001”](http://www.aic.gov.au/publications/current%20series/tandi/261-280/tandi269/view%20paper.html), Trends and issues in crime and criminal justice, no. **269**, Nov 2003
- [2] Andrew Leigh & Christine Neill, [“Do Gun Buybacks Save Lives? Evidence from Panel Data”](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/aler/ahq013), American Law and Economics Review, Vol **12** (2) pp 462–508, Aug 2010 [[PDF](http://andrewleigh.org/pdf/GunBuyback_Panel.pdf)]
- [3] Wang-Sheng Lee & Sandy Suardi, [“The Australian Firearms Buyback and Its Effect on Gun Deaths”](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1465-7287.2009.00165.x), Contemporary Economic Policy, Vol **28** (1) pp 65–79, Jan 2010 [[PDF](http://www.ssaa.org.au/capital-news/2008/2008-09-04_melbourne-uni-paper-Aust-gun-buyback.pdf)]
- [4] Jeanine Baker & Samara McPhedran, [“Gun Law and Sudden Death – Did the Australian Firearms Legislation of 1995 Make a Difference?”](http://bjc.oxfordjournals.org/content/47/3/455), British Journal of Criminology, Vol **47** (3), 2007 [[PDF](http://moveleft.org/dog_ban/br_j_criminology_2006_.pdf)]

Comment: … and as always I’d appreciate if downvotes were accompanied by feedback.

Comment: I know this is an old Q/A but I was taking a look at this myself and find one thing confusing, your text implies a reduction in suicide in general but the chart mentions "firearm suicides" which no doubt decreased. This Australian government site from what I can see seems to indicate while firearm suicides decreased a lot it really only ended up with other methods being used: https://www.aihw.gov.au/suicide-self-harm-monitoring/data/deaths-by-suicide-in-australia/suicide-deaths-over-time

Comment: @PeterJ A long time ago indeed, and I don’t have time now to re-research this now (writing this answer took a *long* time), but please note that my answer doesn’t just “imply” a *general* reduction, it states this *outright*: “the NFA and buyback were correlated with a significant reduction in firearms related deaths, *and no balancing increase in non-firearms related deaths*.” (The English in this answer is a bit … unorthdox: on some days my writing skills just aren’t very good. The intended meaning here is that decrease in gun-related suicides wasn’t compensated by other methods of suicide.)

Comment: @PeterJ I’d have to re-review the evidence to see if it truly supports this claim, but I distinctly remember that this was one of the stronger conclusions of reference [2]. Please also note my bullet point about “Compensation”: apparently there was a *brief* uptick in other methods of suicide, allegedly caused by a continuing, previous trend, which abated over time.

Comment: @PeterJ That said, it’s hard to bring this into line with the official numbers you’ve linked to. For now I remain puzzled. I can’t remember whether any of the papers explain this apparent discrepancy. If they fail to explain it, we must probably question their conclusions. (One potential explanation would be to regress out long-term trends; I don’t remember if this was done, but it might disentangle a total, long-term increase from sudden reductions. Another thing is that the official figure shows absolute number, not accounting for population growth.)

Answer (score 11):

From: [Gun Control Effects on Crime and Murder](http://gun.laws.com/gun-control/gun-control-effects-on-crime-and-murder)

> Very much like the larger scope of the
>   entire gun control debate, **it is of no
>   surprise that both opposing factions
>   will reach a stalemate in regarding
>   gun control and its actual effects on
>   crime and murder**.  However, it is
>   important to note that arguments and
>   debate on the subject are not the main
>   reason as to being able to
>   determinately claim fact to one or the
>   other, but it is the discrepancy in
>   the statistics and facts themselves
>   that lend to dispute.

Furthermore the author goes on to state some statistics:

> In general, it has been reported that
>   60% to 70% of all homicides involve
>   firearms.  Out of this firearms, about
>   80% involved handguns.  Since the
>   implementations of more restrictions
>   and regulations involving the
>   purchases, possession, or carrying of
>   handguns have been more explicitly
>   stressed since the 1970s and 1980s,
>   there has been a general decline of
>   firearm related violent related
>   crimes, particularly homicides.  **From
>   the early 1990s to turn of the
>   century, this decline has been at a
>   steady average at about 10% each year,
>   with a total decline of about 50%. 
>   Such statistical reports will provide
>   for factual evidence extensively
>   showing how crime can be reduced with
>   pro gun control implementations.  Not
>   only do these numbers prove a positive
>   effect about gun control, but it is a
>   drastic and impressive one.**  Another
>   report showed that there are about 6.3
>   million violent crimes committed in
>   1999.  Violent crimes including rape or sexual assault, robber, and assault
>   were considered for this statistic. 
>   Out of those crimes, just over 500,000
>   involved the use of firearms, which is
>   about 8% of the total estimation of
>   violent crimes.  This statistic
>   essentially shows that firearms are
>   not necessarily properly correlated
>   with their use during violent crimes,
>   and therefore, extensive gun control
>   laws deem to be excessive and unfair
>   to those citizens legally allowed to
>   own and use them.  **An example of how
>   stricter gun control laws did not aid
>   in lowering crime rates is Washington
>   D.C.  In 1976, D.C. adopted what was
>   to be considered one of the few
>   extremely restrictive gun control
>   policies in the country. The murder
>   rate since the time of new gun control
>   policy rose 134%.**  Yet another example
>   is New York City, which also
>   implemented similarly stringent gun
>   laws as D.C. had similar results.  In
>   the early 1970s, about 19 % of
>   homicides involved pistols, and
>   shortly after the new laws were in
>   place, this number rose to about 50%. 
>   Furthermore, the restriction of
>   firearms allowed for only 28,000
>   lawfully possessed or acquired
>   firearms, yet law enforcement
>   estimations had the number at 1.3
>   million illegal handguns in the city. 
>   Conversely, states with fewer
>   restrictions such as New Hampshire and
>   Vermont, have proven to the safest of
>   all the states, with Vermont ranking
>   in at 49th in crime and 47th in
>   murders.

I emphasized a few important points.

The conclusion I draw is that there are situations where gun control appears to directly save lives, but in other situations gun control has almost no effect.  Though the [crack epidemic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crack_epidemic) may have simply outweighed the effects of gun control.  Another reason that these laws may have been ineffective is that guns can be purchased at [gun shows in other states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_shows_in_the_United_States), which may render gun control laws in nearby areas mostly useless.

Comment: The first half of the quote seems to be a [cum hoc ergo propter hoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation) fallacy (it is [rarely a good idea](http://www.venganza.org/images/PiratesVsTemp.png) to assume causal connection between two societal trends based on a single example). The other half could easily be cherry-picked data; the methodology is not declared, and you will probably find a few examples to for prejudice, given a large enough data set.

Comment: @Tgr: I think the first part is common sense, and it needs to mentioned that no one has clearly won this debate from the view of the layman.

Comment: sorry, I meant the first part of the statistics (comparing global trends on homicide and gun control).

Comment: The second part: it is important to note that US census 2009 has NY city with 8.3 million people, while Vermont's total state population is .6 million. Population densities correlate strongly with crime.

Comment: "The conclusion I draw is that there are situations where gun control appears to directly save lives, but in other situations gun control has almost no effect." One could say exactly the same for penicillin, which has saved millions of lives!?

Comment: Also, what makes you think the law.com site is reputable - not peer reviewed and they don't cite their sources. Also, the page you mention has a link to subscribe to the NRA and a link to buy guns... IMHO it's a very poor reference, certainly not authoritative.

Comment: This is a nice statistic. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_firearm-related_death_rate Compare for an example Switzerland(guns at home) and Germany(strict gun laws). Switzerland has 10 times higher rate of gun related homicides than Germany (with similar culture and economic status)

Comment: @all Feel free to edit my answer however anyone likes.  I would like to update myself, but I'm having trouble finding the time to commit to improving the answer.

Comment: Is this US? Global? Otherwise? The post doesn't really show the geographic coverage.

Comment: I actually loved how this answer is relatively short and still somewhat appealing. :)

Answer (score 6):

**There is some evidence from state to state comparisons that gun control laws and gun ownership show some relationship to deaths from firearm use**

For many observers outside the USA it seems obvious that the lax US attitude to gun control is a major contributor to the high rate of death from gun use in the USA (the USA is an outlier in death rates at least among developed countries). But these international comparisons are always going to be subject to many confounding factors. However, different states inside the US have very different rules about firearm ownership and control so this might offer better, less confounded an more relevant, evidence for whether tighter control is useful in the US context.

A recent piece of research in the journal [JAMA Internal Medicine](http://archinte.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=1661390) analyses the internal state by state legislation and its relationship to death rates. The study concludes:

> A higher number of firearm laws in a state are associated with a lower rate of firearm fatalities in the state, overall and for suicides and homicides individually. As our study could not determine cause-and-effect relationships, further studies are necessary to define the nature of this association.

Two visualizations of their data are worth repeating. The first is a map of death rates and legislative "strength":

[image]

The second image contains some scatter plots of the data, state by state:

[image]

It is also worth noting the limitations of the study. In the authors own words (i've highlighted some of the key issues):

> Our study has limitations. First, *the legislative strength score, which tallies a single point per law, has not been validated*. Neither has the weighted Brady scoring system, and we are unaware of any such scoring systems that have been validated. Our results, which divided states into quartiles of legislative strength, were essentially the same with either of these scoring systems. Second, we examined only deaths by firearms, not nonfatal firearm injuries; fatality was our primary outcome. Approximately 2.6 nonfatal firearm injuries are treated for every fatal firearm injury. Third, we were unable to control for the enforcement of firearm laws or the exploitation of loopholes, which may vary between states. Fourth, although we adjusted for many state-based factors associated with firearm fatalities, there may be additional factors not considered in our model that are relevant (eg, city laws and police enforcement). However, we included nonfirearm suicides and nonfirearm homicides in some of our analyses to control for the potential role of additional factors. We found little evidence of substitution—rates of firearm-related deaths were not correlated with rates of nonfirearm violent death in the multivariable model. Fifth, although we found that states with more legislation have lower fatality rates, ie, are “safer” states, in a cross-sectional ecological study *we could not determine if the greater number of laws were the reason for the reduced fatality rates.* The association could have been confounded by firearm ownership rates or other unaccounted factors.

So, in conclusion, there appears to be some relationship between tighter gun control and gun deaths (for both suicides and homicides). But the quality of evidence required to demonstrate causality is not yet available.

Comment: Another thing they didn't control for (not sure if they included it in "enforcement" caveat) - how many homicides were attributed to legally owned vs illegally owned weapons. Both AZ and NM - looking at the end of the list#2 - are plausibly likely to have tons of the latter, due to narcotics related issues.

Comment: @DVK It would be very difficult to control for illegal versus legally owned weapons. State laws are not uniform. They vary widely. In fact, legality varies at a city and even borough level. As a resident of Arizona, and having been raised in New Mexico, I confess that I was non-plussed upon reading your supposition that we are more illegal weapon- and narcotic-afflicted than other border states e.g. Texas or California, or other states in general. Also, the population of New Mexico is tiny, compared to the other states of the USA.

Comment: That map of the us is suspect.  It shades VT has purple, but murder (by any means) is rare in the state.  In 2011for example there were only four murders using guns, all the rest are suicides.  http://www.burlingtonfreepress.com/story/news/local/vermont/2014/07/17/vt-gun-deaths-outpaced-car-accident-deaths/12756651/

Comment: I'm also kind of curious if the real correlation here is between a higher number of gun control laws and a smaller number of guns.

Answer (score 2):

According to the BBC article [Missouri gun murders 'rose after law repeal'](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-26222578),

> Reporting soon in the Journal of Urban Health, the researchers will say that the [gun control law's] repeal resulted in an **immediate spike in gun violence and murders**.
>
> The study links the abandonment of the background check to an additional 60 or so murders occurring per year in Missouri between 2008 and 2012.
>
> "Coincident exactly with the policy change, there was an **immediate upward trajectory to the homicide rates** in Missouri," said Prof Daniel Webster, director of the Johns Hopkins Center for Gun Policy and Research.

It looks like the paper cited has sensible controls for the conclusions:

> "That upward trajectory did not happen with homicides that did not involve guns; it did not occur to any neighbouring state; the national trend was doing the opposite – it was trending downward; and it was not specific to one or two localities – it was, for the most part, state-wide," he told BBC News.
>
> The team said it took account of changes that occurred in policing levels and incarceration rates, trends in burglaries, and statistically controlled for other possible confounding factors such as shifts in unemployment and poverty.

According to the BBC the underlying study is to-be reported in the Journal of Urban Health. If vetted, the study would be compelling evidence that the absence of gun control laws correlates with higher gun violence and murders.

**Edit** Referencing CBC story [Mass shootings in the U.S.: Guns, glory, broken dreams *A new study sheds light on why mass shootings in the U.S. are 'an exceptionally American problem'*, Aug 25, 2015](http://www.cbc.ca/news/world/mass-shootings-in-the-u-s-guns-glory-broken-dreams-1.3203335).  This article states that Adam Lankford recently presented at the American Sociological Association's conference the results along the lines of the following:

> Using data compiled by the New York City Police Department in its 2012 report on active shooting incidents in the U.S. and around the world, as well as data from a 2014 FBI report, Lankford determined that the U.S. had 90 mass shooting incidents during that time frame.

...

> America's **gun culture and the widespread availability of firearms, contributes to the country's mass shooting problem**, the study says. It found that American mass shooters were more likely to arm themselves with multiple weapons, though they killed fewer people than shooters in other countries.

...

> While Lankford's study suggested a strong link between the civilian firearm ownership rate and the number of public mass shooters in the United States, he said **there could be other factors** that make the U.S. especially prone to public mass shooting incidents.
>
> America puts **more pressure on its citizens to succeed professionally and financially** than other countries, Lankford discusses in his study, and when Americans have bad experiences at work or school and fail to achieve their goals, they are more likely to **respond with acts of violence**.

...

> Then there's also the **idolization of fame**, which appears uniquely American, according to Lankford. Increasingly in the U.S., especially among young people, becoming famous is considered the ultimate form of success.

...

> "Unfortunately, **due to some combination of strains, mental illness and American idolization of fame**, some mass shooters succumb to terrible delusions of grandeur, and **seek fame and glory through killing**," his study says. They realize that the only way they will become a household name is by killing innocent people.

Which is all to say, according to the article and the underlying study the exceptionally high number of American gun massacres is linked to:

1. gun prevalence,
2. gun culture,
3. mental illness,
4. cultural expectations for success, and
5. desire for fame.

That is to say: Gun control would reduce the prevalence, but I think it is fair to say that one should be cautious of using gun control as a solution because the underlying demand for mass murders in America will remain (as created by mental illness, cultural expectations, and desire for fame).

Comment: -1. The only way you can see the paper's conrtols as "sensible" is if you desperately want to believe the author's desired conclusion. As I noted in [this answer](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19639/did-a-new-study-prove-that-relaxing-gun-control-increases-murder-rates/19640#19640), he **cherry-picked** a state that **had an atypically rising murder rate** BEFORE the gun control law changed; AND failed to note the curial fact that **the rise rate actually SLOWED after the law passed in that state**.

Comment: "The study links the abandonment of the background check to an additional 60 or so murders occurring per year in Missouri between 2008 and 2012.". also includes the worst years of the great recession.